# Place to buy travel plug adapters and a USB stick in Hyderabad?

Tags: india, electronic-items, power, hyderabad

I'm in Hyderabad and looking for an electronics store where I can buy plug adapters and a USB memory stick. I haven't been able to locate a store with plug adapters in Banjara Hills yet, even in the large GVK One mall.

Anyone know of any stores? It can be outside of Banjara Hills.

Comment: What does `good` mean to you? We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE so this question is unanswerable here.

Comment: I have removed the subjectiveness caused by 'good'. It reads to me that the user wants power adapters and usb sticks and simply can't find any, and as a traveler doesn't know where to look, or what to use to find them. Perhaps someone familiar with Hyderabad could recommend ANY store that might help the user, before the imminent closure....

Comment: Did you try Amazon or Flipkart, they'll deliver to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I posted this I tried logging in to Amazon India with my US account to see what would happen, and it worked.

Then it was just a matter of entering my hotel's address as the delivery address, and using their phone number as well (after confirming with the front desk that they'd accept a delivery from Amazon).

I paid for one day delivery and it worked perfectly. This was infinitely easier than spending time going to random shops and being limited to their small stock of items. Hope this helps someone out.